# как можно решить данную проблему?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton'
import { blue } from '@mui/material/colors';
import * as Mui from '@mui/material';
import { Grid } from '@mui/material';
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';

function App() {
  return (
<Container className={classes.cardGrid} maxWidth="xl">
    <Grid
        container
        direction="row"
        justify="space-evenly"
        alignItems="stretch"
        spacing={2}
    >
        {
            toiletOverviews.map(data => (
                <Grid item
                      key={`GridItem-${data.id}`} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={2} xl={1}
                >
                    <Box
                        display="flex"
                        flexDirection="column"
                        style={{height: '100%', backgroundColor: 'purple'}}
                    >
                        <Typography
                            variant="h5"
                            style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: blue[800]}}
                        >
                            {data.title}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography
                            style={{backgroundColor: blue[600]}}
                        >
                            Some text
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography
                            style={{backgroundColor: blue[400]}}
                        >
                            Some other text
                        </Typography>
                    </Box>
                </Grid>
            ))
        }
    </Grid>
</Container>

  )
}

export default App;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
/>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
/>

    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проблему можно решить импортировав или определив переменные `toiletOverviews` и `classes`